# Easily writing Bundles

Tags: cocoa, bundle

How can I write bundles in Cocoa without much "fuzz" around it? I just want to have a bundle with an Info.plist, a Contents Folder, and that folder should contain a couple of files.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to do with this bundle?

Comment: It is intended to be a backup container for multiple other non-bundle PLists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are simply looking to create directories with Cocoa, check out NSFileManager. It has the method:

> -createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:

I also assume that you have read - [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html)

This guide will provide you with the complete anatomy of a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Then just make one:

```
mkdir My.bundle
cd My.bundle
mkdir Contents
cd Contents
touch Info.plist
mkdir Resources
open Info.plist
```

That should get you started nicely.

**Edit:** You run this in Terminal.app, of course.

Comment: Is there a cocoa-only way of doing this, one that uses Cocoa Classes , if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [file wrappers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFileWrapper_Class/), assuming you're using Cocoa and not Cocoa Touch.

Create the bundle out of file wrappers from the inside out, with every directory and file being modeled by a file wrapper. Then, write the outermost file wrapper to the bundle URL.